# How to filter array values in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have two page home and listing page. Home page contains list of services with checkbox here user once select some service and submit, page redirecting to listing page. I have stored selected values in localstorage and passed to listing page everything working fine but filter is not working. Here I'm filtering S_Services its not working. How to filter if I selected only Regular Service its working but if I select Regular Service, Software Faults some like this I selected its not working. How to display if any one match in that S_Services?

Could someone help me out?

```js
.controller('ListingCtrl', [
 '$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window', '$filter','$ionicPopover','$ionicLoading',
   function($scope, $http, $location, $window, $filter, $ionicPopover, $ionicLoading) {
 $scope.$watch(function() {
  return window.localStorage.getItem("searchstore")
  },
  function(searchstore) {
     $scope.query = searchstore;
    console.log($scope.query);
  });

 $scope.clearSearch = function() {
   window.localStorage.setItem("searchstore", "");
  };
 
 $http.get('*****').success(function(data,dealers,response)
   {  
   $scope.dealers = data;
            console.log(dealers);
   
   });
}])
    //in console i am getting list of dealers
    console i am getting like this
    1: Object
    $$hashKey: "object:28"
    Dealer_id: "55b24172c7d354f30cda0e7f"
    Legal_Name: "Adtiya Samsung Store"
    S_Address: Object
    address_line1: "No.80, Marks Road"
    area: "madiwala"
    city: "Bangalore"
    state: "Karnataka"
    zipcode: "560068"
    S_Date_add: "2015-07-24T13:45:23.927Z"
    S_Email_id: "aditiya@gmail.com"
    S_Store: "samsung"
    Store_Name: "Adtiya Samsung Store"
    S_Services:"Regular Service,Software Faults,Hardware Faults"
    Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles"
    Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles"
    2: Object
    $$hashKey: "object:28"
    Dealer_id: "55b24172c7d354f30cda0e7g"
    Legal_Name: "sri shakthi mobile services"
    S_Address: Object
    address_line1: "3rd street"
    area: "madiwala"
    city: "Bangalore"
    state: "Karnataka"
    zipcode: "560068"
    S_Date_add: "2015-07-24T13:45:23.927Z"
    S_Email_id: "rajs@gmail.com"
    S_Store: "nokia"
    Store_Name: "sri shakthi mobile service"
    S_Services:"Settings Faults,Regular Service,Hardware Faults"
    Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia mobiles"
    Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia mobiles"
    3: Object
    $$hashKey: "object:28"
    Dealer_id: "55b24172c7d354f30cda0e7h"
    Legal_Name: "sun mobile service center"
    S_Address: Object
    address_line1: "23rd main ,2nd cross"
    area: "madiwala"
    city: "Bangalore"
    state: "Karnataka"
    zipcode: "560068"
    S_Date_add: "2015-07-24T13:45:23.927Z"
    S_Email_id: "sprtive23@gmail.com"
    S_Store: "nokia,samsung"
    Store_Name: "sun mobile service center"
    S_Services:"Regular Service"
    Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles"
    Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles
```

```html
<div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
      <label class="item-input-wrapper" >
        <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="query" >
      </label>
     <button class="button button-icon ion-ios-close-outline"     ng-click="clearSearch()" id="iconcolor"  >clear</button>
    </div>
    <div class="list card" data-ng-init="nearme()" data-ng-repeat="dealer in dealers |  filter:query ">
         <div class="item item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right" href="#">
          <h2>{{dealer.Store_Name}}</h2> 
          <p>{{dealer.S_Address.area}} {{dealer.S_Address.city}}</p> 
       <p>{{dealer.S_Services}}</p>
      </div> 
      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a custom filter to filter based on an `dealer` object's property as given below.

```
     .filter('customFil', function () {

return function (dealers, query) {
    var obj = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < dealers.length; i++) {
        var tokenisedString = query.split(",");
        var isPresent = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < tokenisedString.length; j++) {
            if (dealers[i].S_Services.toUpperCase().includes(tokenisedString[j].toUpperCase())) {
                obj.push(dealers[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/divm/rpbn6u23/12/) is an working example

Comment: if i search Software,hardware it should show Adtiya Samsung Store,sri shakthi mobile service rit but its not showing.even my code also same thing working

Comment: that's because it is case sensitive...  search for `Software Faults,Hardware` you would get `Samsung Store`

Comment: okey if i search Regular Service,Hardware Faults it should show Adtiya Samsung Store,sri shakthi mobile service right.but it showing only sri shakthi mobile service

Comment: here i need to show list where ever services matched

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/divm/rpbn6u23/2/ this displays only those who have all the queries separated by ","

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/divm/rpbn6u23/3/ this displayes those who have atleast one of the queries separated by ","

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85399/discussion-between-divya-mv-and-sree-mohan).

Comment: i have added here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875847/angularjs-filter-wih-two-fields-not-working